# Need advise for Web Control REST LED Switch

Tags: raspbian, gpio, node.js, mysql, switches

I would like to seek for advise and help on REST API - Web Control Interface LED Switch. I been searching over the net and seems kinda lost, so I hope you guys could help me out with it as soon as possible.

**Stuff I'm using:**

**Hardware** - Raspberry PI and LED

**Software** - node.js, ejs, express, pi-gpio

**Database** - mySQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Heimcontrol.js](https://ni-c.github.io/heimcontrol.js/) does exactly what you ask using roughly the same software (`node.js socket.io express.js mongodb`). It’s probably more elaborate than what you had in mind, but it should be a really good resource when you run into problems.